# The type or namespace name `Xml' does not exist in the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to read a signed xml with a

```
Using System.Security;
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml signedXml = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml(lic);
```

First Unity/VS complained that

> VS > Error    11    The type or namespace name `Xml' does not exist in
>   the namespace`System.Security.Cryptography'. Are you missing an
>   assembly reference?

So I added a reference to System.Security in Visual Studio (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Security.dll)...but Unity keeps complaining that

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Xml' does not exist in the
>   namespace`System.Security.Cryptography'. Are you missing an assembly
>   reference?

I then tried to directly copy the 'System.Security.dll' inside the asset folder...but still the same message!

What am I doing wrong please? What has to be done?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace is excluded from the unity's default `.Net 2.0 Subset` API. Most probably `.Xml` is also stripped. So do one of the following:

1. in Unity click on Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + B to open the build menu, click on `player settings`. In inspector find `API Compatability Level` which is set to `.Net 2.0 Subset` by default. Change it to `.Net 2.0` which includes the rest of the previously stripped classes/namespaces.
2. if the error persists then make sure that the .dll you are copying into Unity is from .net 2.0 framework. Unity can't import libraries targeting framework higher than .net 2.0

This is what is excluded from the unity's `Subset` API:
https://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html

Sorry, I couldn't find the current version of this document

**EDIT:**

as @user2737085 suggested - you'd also have to add `mcs.rsp` file to your `Assets` folder. `mcs.rsp` should be a text file containing the following line:

```
-r:System.Security.dll
```

Comment: Nika,

Thank you very much for your help!

I've done as you advised and it works!

...but I had to add a 'mcs.rsp' file containing '-r:System.Security.dll' in the project asset folder!
Thanks again!

Comment: @user2737085 cool, I've edited the answer for the lost souls of the future